# Template inheritence: pass data from parent to child

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to implement a generic html table template.
In the parent template (generic_table.html), I just loop over a list of dict to build an HTML table.

```
<table class="table " >
  <tbody>
        {% for elt in table %}
          <tr> 
            {% block table_td %}
              <td >{{ el.value }}</td>
            {% endblock %}
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the child template, I would like to add custom columns, with edit or delete buttons for example.

```
{% extends "generic_table.html" %}
  {% block table_td %}
  {{super()}}
    <td> <button> MY EDIT BTN </button </td>
    <td> <button> MY DELETE BTN </button </td>

  {% endblock table_td %}
```

It works well, but to implement the custom button, I need to access to the parent loop context (in order to have the current ID for example). Is there a way to pass data from the parent to the child template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of pattern, you may need the keyword [`scoped`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope) to define the parent block :

#### Base template :

```
<tbody>
    {% for elt in table %}
      <tr>
          <td >{{ elt.value }}</td>
          {% block table_td scoped %}
          {% endblock %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

#### Child template :

```
{% extends "generic_table.html" %}

{% block table_td %}
    <td> <button> MY EDIT BTN {{ elt.value }}  </button> </td>
    <td> <button> MY DELETE BTN  {{ elt.value }} </button> </td>
{% endblock %}
```